# visual code coverage in travis-ci

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, travis-ci

I've got some github projects which I want to test with code coverage. The only way I found (see [blog post](http://ocramius.github.com/blog/automated-code-coverage-check-for-github-pull-requests-with-travis/)) to achieve this is to write a custom script that counts code coverage XML lines and outputs `Code coverage is 74.32%, which is below the accepted 80%`. Displaying code coverage in HTML is way better, but is it possible in travis-ci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travic CI doesn't support any persistent storage. One suggestion would be to create a custom script and run `phpunit --coverage-html`, next send the contents of the output dir to your own server using something like rsync.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. How about passing this data within email notification after the code-coverage is done on a travis worker?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, seems like a good idea as well. Not sure if sendmail is working if you use a custom php script in travis, but you could at least try.

Comment: You could use a service like [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) and push the results there.

Answer (score 13):

You can use https://coveralls.io/ together with Travis to display coverage nicely. Example can be found here: https://coveralls.io/r/phpmyadmin/error-reporting-server

PS: I know this is quite old question, but I've found it just now when searching for something else.